# Can't add one of my Google Apps for Work accounts

Tags: google-account, google-apps

I have several Google Apps accounts, and two of them I've added without a problem. I'm trying to add a third, and after I enter my email address, password and two-factor token from Authy, it tells me "Sorry, there seems to be a problem. Please try again." I've tried this over several days.

I did use to have this account on my phone, but it seems I can't add it back after a factory reset to revert from an Android N preview.

I can sign into this account just fine from a desktop browser or from the Android browser in incognito mode.

Comment: Same problem here, but for me it started simply after I changed my password. I'm using the Xperia Z3 firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again? I think they fixed whatever was wrong, as it has worked for me today.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked flawlessly this time. Thanks for the tip :-)